# Change include_path or prepend each php file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, php

I have an app which stores some data in `.php` files in `/library/` directory, 
eg. `/library/config.php`.

On my old hosting `library` was in the include path, so I was able do do `require('config.php')` anywhere without providing the real path.

Is there any chance to auto prepend each .php file, to update the include path?

There are some circumstances:

- the app does not follow front controller pattern
- I have no access to `php.ini`
- I have no direct access to any of the dirs already present in `include_path`
- I can't use `php_flag include_path`
- I can't use `php_flag auto_prepend_file`
- some .php files have their own rules in `.htaccess`

Any other way than `ctrl+H` and replace `<?` with `<? set_include_path…`?

Edit:

What I am looking for would be something similar to:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}  !-F
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}  !-d
RewriteRule (^*\.php)$ /library/$1 [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add [`set_include_path()`](http://php.net/set_include_path) at the top of the file where you need the library files to adjust the include path at runtime (no need to touch `php.ini` or `.htaccess` files).

```
set_include_path(dirname(__FILE__).'/library'.PATH_SEPARATOR.get_include_path());
```

This prepends your library path to the current include path and makes the files there directly available. You need to adjust `'/library'` to match your library path (relative to the current file's location).

Comment: That's my `ctrl+h` solution. Any other?

Comment: I would recommend to do the above once in a common file and include that in every other file that needs it. This makes your code much more maintainable, since you do not need to touch every file if something changes (like the library path). Also, i would recommend not to use short open tags (use `<?php` instead of `<?`), since they clash with xml declarations. This can lead to some trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Is `ini_set()` forbidden too? Which allows you to modify the `include_path` too.

Comment: Neither `ini_set` nor `set_inlcude_path` are disabled, but that's not the case here.